# Tests for Proc::ProcessTable module fail after successful build on Solaris

Tags: perl

I am getting the error below during `make test` on Solaris even though the `make` command executed successfully.

> Can't load '/e/scripts/Proc-ProcessTable-0.53/blib/arch/auto/Proc/ProcessTable/ProcessTable.so' for module Proc::ProcessTable: ld.so.1: perl: fatal: /e/scripts/Proc-ProcessTable-0.53/blib/arch/auto/Proc/ProcessTable/ProcessTable.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 at /usr/perl5/5.10/lib/5.10.0/sun4-solaris-thread-multi-64/DynaLoader.pm line 203.

Can someone help and suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: The obvious diagnosis is that you are trying to load a 32-bit shared object from a 64-bit version of perl, but it is hard to imagine how you have managed to do so given your description. Why have you chosen to do the installation step by step instead of just running `cpan Proc::ProcessTable`? Please show the whole build process log.